# I am Trying to solve a problem in hacker rank. My algorithm is okay but can't find the output

Tags: algorithm, max

I am Trying to solve a problem in hacker rank, Which title is breaking best and worst. but the function I write didn't give proper output for any of the test case but in my visual code ide it is giving the correct result.
The problem is find out the sequence of increasing number and decreasing. finally return the result in two space separated integers. I've write the function to the point and my IDE is giving the accurate result but in hacker rank it's giving error
[here is the link of problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/breaking-best-and-worst-records/problem)

my solution approach

```
function breakingRecords(scores) {
let increase = 0;
let decrease =0;

{code that properly increase the value of
increase and decrease.}
}


const result = (increase,decrase);
return result;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I made mistake in my code is I return my value normally in two variable but those value I have to return in array like

```
const result = [increase,decrase];
return result;
```

That's it!!